# "error":"IndexMissingException[[ObjectiveIndex] missing]","status":404

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch

I am using mongodb 2.4.5 and elasticsearch 0.90.5. When I am creating an Index on ObjectiveIndex it show  "error":"IndexMissingException[[ObjectiveIndex] missing]","status":404.

```
 #!/bin/sh
 curl -XPUT "localhost:9200/_river/ObjectiveIndex/_meta" -d'
 {
   "type": "mongodb",
   "mongodb": {
     "servers": [
       { "host": "localhost", "port": 27017 }
     ],
     "options": { "secondary_read_preference": true },
     "db": "mydatabase",
     "collection": "pages"
   },
   "index": {
     "name": "ObjectiveIndex",
     "type": "Objective"
   }

}'
```

Comment: Have you verified that `localhost:9200/_river/ObjectiveIndex/_meta` is there?

Comment: Do'nt know where river meta is stored. Can any one explain how it works ?